# Replace value in dimension string[]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, replace

How can i replace Value in dimension? 
My string dimension looks like :

```
string[] map = new string[]
            {
                "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+", 
                "|{0}X2X3X4X5X6X7X8X9X10                                  B                 |",
                "|A X                                                                       |",
                "|XXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                    |",
                "|XXX                                                                       |",
                "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
                "|XXX                 X                                                     |",
                "|XXX              XXXX                                                     |",
                "|    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
                "|                                                                          |",
                "|                                                                          |",
                "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+",
            };
```

I need to just replace {0} to  for ie "C"

I try with 
`map.Replace` but it doesn't work  how can i replace values in this point?

After replaceing it should looks like :

```
string[] map = new string[]
                {
                    "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+", 
                    "|CX2X3X4X5X6X7X8X9X10                                   B                 |",
                    "|A X                                                                       |",
                    "|XXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                    |",
                    "|XXX                                                                       |",
                    "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
                    "|XXX                 X                                                     |",
                    "|XXX              XXXX                                                     |",
                    "|    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
                    "|                                                                          |",
                    "|                                                                          |",
                    "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+",
                };
```

In normal string its easy way with :

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
               <productOrderNumber>{0}</productOrderNumber>";
var NewXML = String.Format(xml, "HI");
```

How can i do the same thing with string[] ? Please explain on my example.

Comment: That's not called a "dimension", it's an "array". See duplicate.

Comment: You'are right thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Format()` is for string, in your case, it's string[]. So it doesn't work like your expected

To "format" your string, you must do your action for each string, by `Select` following

```
map = map.Select(x => string.Format(x, "C")).ToArray();
```

And if you only want to update the 2nd line in your question

Try

```
map[1] = string.Format(map[1] , "C");
```

Comment: Yes it works perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Replace directly on string arrays, you have to select single item and then use Replace.

```
map = map.Select(x => x.Replace("{0}", "C")).ToArray();
```

Comment: You answear is better and works well , but what about when i want to replace single line map[1] ? How can i replace only char in line1?

Comment: you can use same Select for single char as well as for whole line also. Just use your char instead of {0}. Have you tried that? any errors?

Comment: I tried but your example replace {0} in whole array.  When i have {0} and {0} in another lines both will be replaced by C . Can you edit your Answer and add code how to replace chosen line? for example replace {0} to C only in line nunmber 1 map[1]. Cannot do that map[1] = map[1].Select(x => x.Replace("{0}", "C")).ToArray();